React Native Expo, GET location in background
When I test the application, everything is ok..it works in the background, but when it is in the background, it doesn't record every 10 meters the location change...only when I open the application again
This is part of code
const handleNewLocation = (newLocation) => {
    const { accuracy, latitude, longitude } = newLocation.coords;

    // Ignoriraj ažuriranja ako preciznost nije dovoljno dobra
    if (accuracy > 20) return; // Možete prilagoditi ovu vrijednost

    console.log("New location update received:", newLocation);
    const newCoord = { latitude, longitude };

    // Ubacuje sve lokacije u jednu varijablu
    handleLocationUpdate(newCoord);

    if (!startLoc) {
        setStartLoc(`${latitude},${longitude}`);
        setWaitingForGPS(false); // Postavi waitingForGPS na false nakon što se postavi početna lokacija
    }

    setLocations((prevLocations) => {
        if (prevLocations.length > 0) {
            const lastCoord = prevLocations[prevLocations.length - 1];
            const distanceIncrement = geolib.getDistance(
                lastCoord,
                newCoord
            );

            setTotalDistance((prevTotalDistance) => prevTotalDistance + distanceIncrement);
            console.log(`Distance incremented by ${distanceIncrement} meters.`);
        }

        return [...prevLocations, newCoord];
    });

    // Postavi regiju na aktualnu lokaciju
    setRegion({
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.009, // Promijenite delta vrijednosti kako bi postigli željeni zoom
        longitudeDelta: 0.009,
    });

    // Dodaj novu koordinatu u niz ruta
    setRouteCoordinates((prevRouteCoordinates) => [...prevRouteCoordinates, newCoord]);

    // Postavi marker na aktualnu lokaciju
    setMapMarker({
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
    });
};

const startTracking = async () => {
    try {
        const { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            console.error('Permission to access background location was denied');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Permission granted for background location tracking.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while requesting background location permission:', error);
        return;
    }


    setTrackStatusValue(true)

    try {
        // Postavljanje trackStatus na true pomoću AsyncStorage-a
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('trackStatus', 'true');
        console.log('trackStatus set to true.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error setting trackStatus:', error);
    }

    if (paused) {
        console.log("Pauzirano")
        setPaused(false);
        setModalVisible(false);

        return;
    }
    const sub = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
        {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
            distanceInterval: 10, // Notify for each 10 meters moved
        },
        handleNewLocation
    );



    // Registrirajte pretplatu kao pozadinski zadatak
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('location-background-task', {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        distanceInterval: 10,
        showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
        foregroundService: {
            notificationTitle: 'Bicikliranje u tijeku',
            notificationBody: 'Vaša aktivnost je u tijeku i prati se. Kliknite za detalje',
            notificationColor: '#FFFFFF',
        },
    },handleNewLocation
    );

    console.log("Location tracking started.");
    setSubscription(sub);
    setTrackingStarted(true);
    setStartTime(Date.now());
    setElapsedTime(0);

};

This code is a last ditch effort. The last one was that inside startLocationUpdatesAsync I don't call the function handleNewLocation
